# create a directory in existing path in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a directory inside the folllowing path `/var/www/downloads/`  with this String name  `organization.id` but I am getting a `false` as output.

```
    File filePath = new java.io.File("/var/www/downloads/" + organization.id).mkdir();
    String test = filePath.toString();  
    println("--> Path " + test);
```

Comment: http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks. Start using utils added in Java 7 which allows you to know what exactly caused the problem instead of returning `boolean`.

Comment: Also your example doesn't compile since `mkdir()` returns `boolean` but you are storing it in `File`. Another confusing part is: why do you have `java.io.File` in your code? You already have `File filePath` so it looks like you added `java.io.File` or `java.io.*` to your imports. Does `File` type of `filePath` not come from `java.io` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's better to use `java.nio.file.Paths` and `java.nio.file.Files`:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/var/www/downloads/" + organization.id);
if (!Files.exists(path)) {    //    check if directory exists
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(path);
        System.out.println("Directory created SUCCESSFULLY.");
    } catch (IOException e) { //    failed to create
        System.out.println("Directory creation FAILED.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mkdir() returns boolean. 
So assign `new java.io.File("/var/www/downloads/" + organization.id).mkdir();`
     to a boolean value and print it to check.